# How to use a private GitHub repo as a yarn dependency (internal deps not being installed)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a private GitHub repository as a dependency inside a few of our repos at work.

Inside the top-level `package.json`, our dep is defined like:

```
"mycompany-models": "https://github.com/mycompany/mycompany-models#v1.2.0"
```

This works fine, and the source code is installed inside the top-level `node_modules` dir as expected. However, none of the internal dependencies are installed, such that when I do:

```
import mycompanyModels from 'mycompany-models'
```

I get all sorts of errors about dependencies missing:

```
ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "module-resolver" specified
...
Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'
```

Inside the `mycompany-models` repo, if I add an install step, eg:

```
"install": "npm i"
```

And then reinstall dependencies, npm simply hangs forever. What is happening here? Is this just a bad idea, am I forced to transpile everything? Because this is just a private repo, there's no `pre-publish` step with npm, etc...

Answer (score 3):

If the repo isn't being downloaded then make sure you're following this way of importing repos: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Examples:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
```

If the package is being installed and the import is failing, make sure the `main` property on the package.json of the repo points to an existing file. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

That should be all you need to get it up and running, except if you need to transpile the module from the one that is importing it, but that's a different question.

Also, the errors that you are getting like unresolved modules, make sure those modules are in the `dependencies` property of the module package.json and not in the `devDependencies` property.

#### Update

What are you using to transpile the private module?

Have you thought about publishing the module to a private npm registry? https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia

Comment: Also, let me know what are you using to transpile the private module so I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble and other answers don't work for you, try `ssh -T git@github.com`

If your SSH key is password protected, `yarn` will just fail. You need to first enter the password via the command above.

This is from Github's ["Testing your SSH connection" page](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection).

After that I no longer faced the error:

```
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ...
Directory: /home/...
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```